# Updating and making unique duplicated records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, duplicates

My table have duplicate records, same numbers and codes multiple times.
I do not want to delete the duplicate records but appending a `'V'` for instance will make it unique.

I have tried updating the tables myself to no avail using the update statement and setting the values to `'V'` but it's not working thus I am here.

```
Sample data
324 
324           
12369 
12369
12369         
12439          
16855          
4 
4             
6              
151 
151
151           
1515           
4520 
4520
```

Comment: How would you like the three `12369` entries to be fixed?  Appending a "V" only fixes one of them...

Comment: fixing one by appending the 'V' will be fine. I can figure it out from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can help you:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Col1,
       Col1 + REPLICATE('V', ROW_NUMBER() 
                                OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 
                                          ORDER BY (SELECT 0))-1) AS Col1_
FROM yourTable
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Col1 = Col1_;
```

You can preview result in this [[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9f94/1)

Answer (score 1):

You need a strategy for identifying the primary row for each key that you want to keep vs. the ones that you want to change to make the rows unique, even if there is no other information and you don't care which ones.

My approach would be a self-join that excludes the primary rows and updates the other rows by appending an incremental value, for example by using RANK to obtain a unique incremental value for every occurrence.